# Revoke JWT session tokens with a blacklist. Should I create another system for the blacklist for performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, session, redis, jwt

I'm creating a web application (in C++, for performance) where I'm expecting to process a tremendous amount of events per second; like thousands.

I've been reading about invalidating JWT tokens in my web sessions, and the most reasonable solution for that is to have a storage place for blacklisted tokens. The list has to be checked for every request, and what I'm wondering is performance related: **Should I create a separate system for storing my blacklisted tokens (like redis)? Or should I just use the same PostgreSQL database I'm using for everything else?** What are the advantages of using another system?

The reason I'm asking is that I saw many discussions about invalidating JWT tokens online, and many suggest to use redis (and don't explain whether it's just a solution relevant to their design or whether it's a replacement to their SQL database server for some reason). Well, why not use the same database you're using for your web application? Is there a reason that makes redis better for this?

Answer (score 2):

Redis is a lot faster since its stored on memory of the server rather than opening a connection to the DB, querying and returning the results. So if speed is of importance then Redis is what you would want.

The only negative is if the server restarts the blacklisted tokens are gone. Unless you save them on disk somewhere.